# Implementing a nested state machine

Tags: plutus

I am trying to implement a nested state machine with plutus and I'm wondering if it is even a possibility.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You can search the web for "nested state machine Haskell" and you should find quite a lot of information. Translating Haskell to Plutus should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes - qualified. It will eventually depend on what you have in mind.

The code that ***only runs off-chain*** is limited by the capabilities of Haskell.

But the part of the off-chain code that is ***executed on-chain*** (validator) is subject to the limitations of the Plutus Core language which is what runs on-chain. However, I don't know what they are in this case.